# How to make the doorframe not hideous

Tags: doors, outdoor

The frame of my front door looks, for lack of a better word, hideous:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The holes in the frame itself aren't what concerns me--there was a security screen door there before, and I will probably just fill the holes and sand them down until flush with the rest of the frame, problem solved.

But what is going on between the frame and the stucco? It looks like the doorframe was maybe set in the wall with... some foam/caulking? and then left like that?

I have been thinking that maybe I need to buy some wider molding and cover up the foam/caulking, but I'm not sure whether that's what's normally done--most of the doors I've seen don't have wide molding on the frame. Is the solution here to retexture the wall instead? Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the trim of the door flush or almost flush with the stucco? If it is recessed behind the surface of the stucco is good to know too.

Comment: I would say that if anything, the trim of the door is a little recessed behind the surface of the stucco. Not much, but it's noticeable in person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your existing condition I would add another trim profile over the original flat trim that has the nasty beside it. The projection of the new trim profile will help conceal the rough caulk job somebody left. Here is a sketch to help illustrate

[image]

It can be any size you choose, I would not make it too big, but if you prefer a larger width, there nothing holding you back.

Comment: The only thing I would add, when caulking between the new trim and the stucco, use a elastomeric caulk (high flex).  There are some listed for stucco and you can also get textured version that will closer match the texture of the stucco.

Comment: Thanks! One other question. What's the best way to notch the back corner of a piece of trim?

Comment: A table saw is the simplest way to notch the trim, especially if you are going to increase the size of the trim. If you are only going to make the trim wide enough to cover the ugly, 1/4" to 1/2" cover over the edge of the old caulk will improve the look greatly. With that in mind, a hand plane that is sharp, and a little elbow grease will do the trick too. The plane will angle the back corner of the trim the same way the stucco angles a little to meet the trim.