# How to fill space between wall and door

Tags: walls, doors

I am about to attach some trim over some old trim to cover up a particularly ugly doorframe/wall joint. I think before I do this, it may be a good idea to fill it, since otherwise there will be a large-ish space behind my trim. What would be the best filler to use in this case? The gap is too wide for caulk in some cases, I think, but I am not sure what to use instead.

Here are some photos:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is less than an inch, caulk will fill it fine before you cover it with trim.

Use a caulk that has high flex characteristics like a polyurethane based caulk, actually latex with silicone would work too.

Don't need to be too careful, trim will cover up the caulk.

Comment: Check this out too, it is closely related to what you are doing.     http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/75766/how-to-make-the-doorframe-not-hideous/75794#75794